# Bitmap.Save Parameter is not valid

Tags: c#, encoding, bitmap, gdi+, tiff

I'm using `Bitmap.Save(location,coded,parameters)`to save first frame of a tiff image: the encoding scheme used is Tiff format. I then use `saveadd()` and so on. Works like a charm on win 7 64 bit, *but does not work on 32 bit or older windows versions.*

After researching I found it might be due to tiff image encoding processed differently with ones before GDI+.

**Is there a way to overcome this without any drastic changes?**

Sources:

[Parameter is not valid calling Bitmap.Save()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5397544/parameter-is-not-valid-calling-bitmap-save)

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/fi-FI/netfxbcl/thread/1585c562-f7a9-4cfd-9674-6855ffaa8653

Comment: So, you linked to the exact question you are asking, no?  I know it's an old post, but duplication is duplication.

Comment: @Christian 'Parameter is not valid ' is the error at Save() function

Comment: @SethBattin That was related question with no resolution.

Comment: @SethBattin "This question has been asked before and already has an answer. If those answers do not fully address your question, please ask a new question.' - This what SE says about DQs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, Finally found a resolution. The issue is with the compression format given as one of the input parameters for Save() and how GDI+ works.

**Solution 1:**

The format for compression needs to be changed to one that is supported in that windows. For e.g) `(long)EncoderValue.CompressionLZW` compression in .net works in this case instead of `(long)EncoderValue.CompressionCCITT4`.

But the size of the images will be higher than the one produced from CCITT4.
Also CCITT4 is only for bitonal images and LZW fits most images. 
So just think ahead of these issues ahead, as in most places where tiff image creation are used, not much importance is given to compression used and this issue.

Or an alternative solution can be found below [ I have not tried it though]

**Solution 2:**

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/netfxbcl/thread/1585c562-f7a9-4cfd-9674-6855ffaa8653/

**Additional Reading:**

So question on what compression to choose and why may arise for which you can refer to:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3478292/whats-the-recommended-tiff-compression-for-color-photos/3480411#3480411

Answer (score 20):

You must use "long" for the quality parameter

```
EncoderParameters parametre = new EncoderParameters(1);
parametre.Param[0] = new EncoderParameter(System.Drawing.Imaging.Encoder.Quality, (quality as long));
```

or

```
EncoderParameters parametre = new EncoderParameters(1);
parametre.Param[0] = new EncoderParameter(System.Drawing.Imaging.Encoder.Quality, 90L);
```

or

```
long quality=90; //
EncoderParameters parametre = new EncoderParameters(1);
parametre.Param[0] = new EncoderParameter(System.Drawing.Imaging.Encoder.Quality, quality);
```

Comment: Yes, I am using a different parameer but its a long value. No issues with that I guess

Comment: I use MultiFrame, FrameDimesion and Flus as Long

Comment: I am using (long) typecasting for all parameters.

Comment: Mustafa you saved my day. Thank you!